# extract classifier properties from pickled file

Tags: classification, scikit-learn, pickle

I have `*.clf` file which I get from `fit()` of `sklearn`. I fit my data with `SVM` or `KNN` and want to show its properties when using it for predictions. For example I open earlier pickled classifier file and when I print it I get something like this:

```
SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
    decision_function_shape='ovr', degree=3, gamma='scale', kernel='rbf',
    max_iter=-1, probability=True, random_state=None, shrinking=True, tol=0.001,
    verbose=True)
```

How can I get the value of, for example, `gamma` to print out it somewhere else except for traversing it as `string`? Because at first I have to define either it's `SVM` or `KNN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
clf = SVC()
clf.fit(X, y)

print(clf.get_params())
```

Comment: thanks! I should have looked at some documentation first)